# plt.saveFigure to path containing Chinese characters show UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` to draw figure and then save to a path. Unfortunately, when i save the figure to a path containing Chinese characters which is not `ascii` character, `UnicodeEncodeError` happens.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_list = [1, 2, 3]
y_list = [3, 4, 6]
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, 'ro')
plt.savefig("/home/easygo/train/datasets/paper_can/scatter/蒙牛纯牛奶-9807.png")
```

The entire error message is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 46-50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I searched on google but ended with no answer.

p.s.

```
system ubuntu 16.04
matplotlib 2.2.2
python 3.6.5
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can the filesystem handle unicode characters in file names?

Comment: system is unbuntu 16.04

Comment: And the file system?